# Why am I getting a cannot read property message in my console when I try to use children property and offsetWidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, children, offsetwidth

I am new to coding and programming and I have been following, on Youtube, a screen recording of a programmer making a responsive thumbnail slider using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I've gotten to a point where I am trying to check if my Javascript was logged into the console, but I continue to get this error message: "script.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null at script.js:3" Commenting line 3 solves the problem but then the same error shows for line 4: "script.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' null at script.js:4"

Can someone tell me why this is happening? My code is below.

```js
const container=document.querySelector(".thumbnail-container");
 const allBox=container.children;
 const containerWidth=container.offsetWidth;
 const margin=30;
 var item=0;
 
 
 // item setup per slide
 
 responsive=[
 {breakPoint:{width:0,item:1}}, //if width greater than 0 (1 will item show)
 {breakPoint:{width:600,item:2}}, //if width greater than 600 (2 will item show)
 {breakPoint:{width:1000,item:4}} //if width greater than 1000 (4 will item show)
 ]
 
 function load(){
  for(let i=0; i<responsive.length;i++){
   if(window.innerWidth>responsive[i].breakPoint.width){
    items=responsive[i].breakPoint.item
   }
  }
  start();
 }
 
 function start(){
  for(let i=0;i<allBox.length;i++){
   //width and margin setup of items
   //allBox[i].style.width=containerWidth/items;
   console.log(allBox[i])
  }
 }
 
 window.onload=load();
```

```html
<div class="thumbnailslider">
   <div class="thumbnailcontainer">
    <div class="artitem">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    5
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    6
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    7
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    8
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <!-- Control Slides -->
   <div class="artcontrols">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: `container` is null because you are querying for selector `thumbnail-container`, but the class in your HTML is `thumbnailcontainer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this line you have misspelled thumbnailcontainer to thumbnail-container

```
const container=document.querySelector(".thumbnailcontainer");
```